# Removing UI Element from Child View SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a SwiftUI view that would act as a sort of home page for an application I am designing. As part of this, I want to include a prominent search bar at the top of the home page. However, perhaps I am a little confused as to how `NavigationView` and `TabBar` work in SwiftUI, because the search bar does not disappear when I navigate into a child page as I want it to you. Here is a gif showcasing what I'm talking about:

[image]

Once I navigated into the specific Test Post, I wanted the search bar to disappear, yet it persist at the top of the page while the view within the NavigationLink changes:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 2.0)
            .frame(width: 99, height: 99, alignment: .topLeading)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

    // I only want all of this displayed within the parent view, the home page.

    NavigationView {
        List(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \String.self) {
            // ... create the view
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("SwiftUI Test"))
    }
    .onAppear{ // do stuff }
}
```

Here is a sample of the code that creates a toolbar at the bottom of the page, separating between this "home page" (entitled FeedView()), and a different page that isn't relevant for now.

```
struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FeedView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Feed")
                }
            // other pages in the navbar
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

What is my issue? How can I remove the search bar from all pages that are not the parent?

---

**EDIT**

After implementing Asperi's changes, I'm running into a new issue. I had to create some new `@State` and `@Binding` variables in order to pass their `showHeader` variable between two classes, and it's a bit slow in response time and in correctly passing the updates about half of the time. Take a look:

[image: broken]

And the relevant code changes: (Parent View)

```
@State private var showHeader = true

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        if showHeader {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                // header
            }
        }

        NavigationView {
            List(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \String.self) {
                key in CategoryRow(nameOfCategory: "\(key)".uppercased(), posts: self.posts[key]!, showHeader: self.$showHeader)
            }
        }
```

(Child View; a CategoryRow element):

```
@Binding var showHeader: Bool

// ...

NavigationLink(destination: ExpandMediaView(post: post)
    .onAppear { self.showHeader = false }
    .onDisappear { self.showHeader = true }
)
```

The code only hits the `.onDisappear` portion of the NavigationLink sometimes. Why?

Comment: The Tabview should be your top View and your search should be in FeedView if that's the only place you want it to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Your search bar is not in navigation view that's why it remains visible after you navigate, because your navigation is performed *within* navigation view, not in full-screen.

So the approach to achieve your goal might be as follows (schematically, as provided code is not testable)

```
@State private var showHeader = true // << add conditional state for header
...
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    if showHeader { // << present header conditionally
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
          Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
              .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 2.0)
              .frame(width: 99, height: 99, alignment: .topLeading)
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
          SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
              .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      }
    }
    // I only want all of this displayed within the parent view, the home page.

    NavigationView {
        List(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \String.self) {
            // ... create the view
            NavigationLink(destination: 
               YourDestinationView()
                  .onAppear { self.showHeader = false } // << hide header
                  .onDisappear { self.showHeader = true } // << show header
            ) { 
              // ... label here
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("SwiftUI Test"))
    }
    .onAppear{ // do stuff }
}
```

Comment: My NavigationView creates another set of components that then have the NavigationLink embedded within it, and I managed to figure out how to pass the `showHeader` variable between the two views. The problem I am having now is that the `showHeader` state seems to update too slowly, and, sometimes, fails to update at all when passing the variables between the views. I will update the post with the changes soon, as well as with a new animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your search bar into List{}